# Storing pointers inside C++ standard library containers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++20, stdmap, std

I am implementing a project, in an enviroment where I am required to create hundreds of millions of `std::string` objects. I am storing these strings in multiple containers, therefore the count (copying) of these objects are multiplied, and is a huge bottleneck for my program.

I am trying to come up with a solution, and my online research has taken me so far. Basically my idea is, given that the strings I construct are constant and unnecessarily copied, I would like to instead allocate my own c-type strings (char arrays), and share these pointers across containers (I need these containers because of different advantages of look-up, insertion, etc...).

The main containers that I use are `std::vector`, `std::map`, `std::unordered_set`. For the last two, I am looking for ways to make these containers compatible with the `char*` type. I employed the help of stackoverflow, created a custom hash function for `std::unordered_set` and a `char*` comparison (less than, "<") for like `std::map<_,_,less_than>`.

To make my questions clear, I am going to list them.

1. Before going into technical issues, is this achievable, or standard usage, or worth striving for ?
2. Comparison function works, insertion is successful. However, given that two pointer can point to the same string, but act like different keys inside an `std::ordered_set` and `std::map`, will I also need something like an equality operator overload to be able to use methods like `contains` or `erase`. For example if `const char* p1 = "beta"` and `const char* p2 = "beta"`, `std::map::erase(p1)` should be able to delete the entry `p2` if present inside `std::map` (suppose two `"beta"` 's are inside different memory positions.`).
3. If I made myself clear, is there a better way ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is moving and forwarding, or just referencing instead of copying not an option? If you're trying to switch away from `std::string` I can almost guarantee that you don't have enough error checking in place.

Comment: @sweenish Moving is not because at a certain point in my program, I need the elements to exist in multiple containers (at least be accessible), References has a similar problem, because they can't be used as key's inside these containers.

Comment: Now, that sounds like a potential design issue.

Comment: `std::string_view` might be an option...

Comment: @sweenish You may be correct, but necessity of thread-safety, and the high-load of the production environment, made me dive into some unorthodox optimizations. I am just considering every option. I may introduce some self error checking for my specific use case if it helps with performance.

Comment: @Jarod42 It crossed my mind, I will look into that.

Comment: `is there a better way?` first we have to know what exactly your program does to answer that question. Now you just described "your way" without explaining what it does.

Comment: Looks like you might be after some sort of reference counted string, a bit like the BSTR from Microsoft's Component Object Model, without the silly encoding of course. Are the strings immutable? Also `char* p1 = "beta"` is naughty and if that compiles then you have a C++ compiler that's too permissive.

Comment: @MarekR I must confess that part of the question is ambiguous, and meant for people who were already in such situation and easily come up with an idea without much detail, because it would be really hard for me to even summarize the damn thing.

Comment: *I am required to create hundreds of millions of std::string objects* -- Are any of these strings duplicates of each other?  If there are a large amount of duplicates, maybe the [flyweight design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) may be an option.  [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html) has one.

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't use it like `char* p1 = "beta"`, I didn't want to complicate inline code (consider it like pseudo-code). For your suggestion, `std::map` that I use is the main container, and acts like a reference counter (not really counts, just stores).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie All the strings are different, they are just duplicated/multiplied because of the containers being used, which I now try to eliminate. Some containers are required because strings are being read from multiple disks in a multi-thread environment, where the disk is another bottleneck.

Comment: From what I read, I would strongly recommend to use a database. Imagine 100million strings with 20 characters on average, would be 2Gbyte data. A database will do all the things that you need in high speed. All kind of sorting, distinctness and relations. I would use it. But maybe  there are requirements that I do not know . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny I was using a database(Redis), and moved to STL containers because of the huge communication bottleneck, and some specific optimizations that I need (like prefix search).

Comment: @ArminMontigny unless the OP actually is implementing a database ;)

Comment: @alagner I am, most certainly, also implementing a only-needed-features database :)

Comment: @ArminMontigny: You're hired.

Comment: @MaxPaython didn't you think about about using boost::multi_index or similar "compound" container? That might solve the problem of sharing keys, or limit it at least.

Comment: @alagner I am considering all options, just for now, trying to make the basic STL work. Also gathering ideas, maybe I am approaching the problem from a wrong angle.

Comment: Since your strings are constant, you may prefer something as `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` for the "primary strings-owner container" (always better than raw pointers; unique pointers do not bring any overhead). `std::string` objects are relatively large (e.g., 32 bytes with libstdc++ or MS STL). On the contrary, they usually apply short string optimization (SSO). If many of your strings are short, then SSO may be more runtime/memory-efficient than allocating each string dynamically. Anyway, the other "indexing" containers may then just contain `std::string_view` objects, as suggested.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks for your suggestions. My strings unfortunately too long to be helped by SSO, so it actually makes my life harder. Trying to minimize RAM usage. I am currently researching `std::string_view`.

Comment: Can you not just put `std::string` objects in a few owning containers and `/*const?*/ std::string*`s in the rest?

Comment: @MaxPaython -- *in an enviroment where I am required to create hundreds of millions of std::string objects.* -- Let's take a step back.  OK, so are the strings similar?  Meaning, do many of them start out the same, but diverge later?  If so, then a `trie` might be an option.  You won't be storing multiple versions of the same prefix.